# Vinyl: rtraverse with a function requiring a constraint shared by all fields

Tags: haskell, vinyl

I have constructed a simple example of a [Vinyl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl-0.5.1) record. First, some language pragmas and imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Vinyl
import Data.Vinyl.Functor
import Control.Applicative
```

the actual example (it employs the [HList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl-0.5.1/docs/Data-Vinyl-Derived.html#t:HList) type synonym for simplicity):

```
mytuple :: HList [Integer,Bool]
mytuple = Identity 4 :& Identity True :& RNil
```

This compiles ok. But now I want to print the Vinyl record using [rtraverse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl-0.5.1/docs/Data-Vinyl-Core.html#v:rtraverse):

```
printi :: Show a => Identity a -> IO (Identity a)
printi (Identity x) = print x *> pure (Identity x)

main :: IO ()
main = rtraverse printi mytuple *> pure ()
```

This gives the following error: `No instance for (Show x) arising from a use of ‘printi’`. Which is expected I guess, because `rtraverse` expects a function with no constraints.

How to solve this? It seems like [`reifyConstraint`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vinyl-0.5.1/docs/Data-Vinyl-Core.html#v:reifyConstraint) will be a part of the solution, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that reifyConstraint will solve this problem. What this function does is convert (or "reify") constraints into datatypes, namely the `Dict` datatype. For example

```
>:t reifyConstraint (Proxy :: Proxy Show) mytuple
(reifyConstraint (Proxy :: Proxy Show) mytuple)
  :: Rec (Dict Show :. Identity) '[Integer, Bool]
```

Each element in this record will have form `Dict (Identity _)`. `Dict` is defined as

```
data Dict c x where Dict :: c x => x -> Dict c x
```

Now you simply need a traversal function which can handle a `(Dict Show :. Identity) a` as an input.

```
printi :: Compose (Dict Show) Identity a -> IO (Compose (Dict Show) Identity a) 
printi x@(Compose (Dict a)) = print a >> return x
```

Note that you don't need a `Show` constraint on `a` - the `Show` class dictionary is stored in the `Dict` datatype. You can rtraverse with this function.

```
main = rtraverse printi (reifyConstraint (Proxy :: Proxy Show) mytuple)
```

Comment: Ah, I see. So `Dict` is a GADT, and pattern-matching on it lets you recover the `Show` constraint for the results of the match?

Comment: That's exactly the case.